# Does Bluebird "map" return early?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

Let's imagine that I have 10 promises running that will be passed to `Promise.map()` with its default concurrency setting of `3`.

If any of the first 3 promises are rejected, will the other 7 be even started?

[Bluebird's docs](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) for `map()` states the following:

> *Promises returned by the mapper function are awaited for and the returned promise doesn't fulfill until all mapped promises have fulfilled as well. If any promise in the array is rejected, or any promise returned by the mapper function is rejected, the returned promise is rejected as well*.

It only states that if all fulfill, then the inner promises are awaited, but it's not clear to me what happens if any of them is rejected.

### Edit

I'm aware that the canonical definition of the `map` function is that the output's length is the same as the size of the input, but I'm not sure if Bluebird honors this.

Comment: can't you write a test and find out?

Comment: Yes, I am doing it right now, but I was hopping if there was something in a dark corner of the docs that addresses this question.

Comment: @epascarello There have been times where I've been *able* to test something, but that would take 20 minutes and I'm comparing many different options so that's more time than I'd like to spend, so I appreciate questions like this. I hope Henrique will share with us if he does find the answer later. :)

Comment: "If any of the first 3 promises are rejected, will the other 7 be even started?" I'm not sure what you mean by this. Promises cannot be "started". You can invoke a function which returns a promise, but Bluebird's `.map()` function does not take an array of functions to invoke. It takes an array of pre-existing promises and simply attaches a `.then()` handler to them. So by the time you're calling Bluebird's `.map()` function, you've already "started" all of those promises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have achieved very similar results to @ssube's answer.

I got 10 promises, that will be resolved or rejected after a increasing timeout. The 4th one (because the array is 0-based) is rejected.

```
const Promise = require('bluebird')

function delay(timeout, err, i) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    if (err) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('Rejected', err.message)
        reject(err)
      }, timeout)
    } else {
      setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('Resolved', i)
        resolve(i)
      }, timeout)
    }
  })
}

const promises = Array.apply(null, {length: 10})
  .map(Function.call, Number)
  .map(function (it) {
    if (it === 3) {
      return delay(500 * it, new Error(it))
    } else {
      return delay(500 * it, null, it)
    }
  })

Promise.map(promises, function (p) {
  console.log('Mapping', p)
  return p.toString()
})
  .then(function (it) {
    console.log('All resolved', it)
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log('Error', err.message)
  })
```

This will yield:

```
> Resolved 0
> Mapping 0
> Resolved 1
> Mapping 1
> Resolved 2
> Mapping 2
> Rejected 3
> Error 3
> Resolved 4
> Resolved 5
> Resolved 6
> Resolved 7
> Resolved 8
> Resolved 9
```

So, the behaviour is the following:

- `Promise.map` is short-circuited whenever one of the promises being mapped is rejected.
- The callback in `map` is never executed for any of the subsequent promises.
- Notice that `Error 3` comes before the deliberately slower promises.
- However, all of the promises are "executed" until they are settled.

Comment: "However, all of the promises are executed until they are settled." Note that promises are not "executed", you can invoke a function which returns a promise. Bluebird's `.map()` simply attaches a `.then()` handler to each promise that you've passed into it.

Comment: Sure @idbehold, I didn't mean it literally. Added some quotation to make this clear.

Answer (score 7):

Taken literally, Bluebird's `Promise.prototype.map` returns *immediately*.

When doing so, it returns a `Promise` that may *not* resolve immediately. I imagine you really want to know how *that* promise behaves and there are a few things to break down here:

> If any of the first 3 promises are rejected, will the other 7 be even started?

Yes. Promises are "started" (that is, scheduled) when you create them. The other 7 will attempt to resolve or are likely enough to do so that you need to assume they will.

Imagine if the browser only allows 4 HTTP connections to a server and you make 10 requests. Those first (failing) 3 will be sent, along with a friend, who may not fail but will certainly run.

You should assume that all promises will invoke their bodies.

> It only states that if all fulfill, then the inner promises are awaited, but it's not clear to me what happens if any of them is rejected.

That's easy enough to test:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');                    

function delayReject(delay, err) {                      
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {                    
    console.log('waiting to reject', err);              
    setTimeout(() => rej(err), delay);                  
  });                                                   
}                                                       

function delayValue(delay, val) {                       
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {                    
    console.log('waiting to resolve', val);             
    setTimeout(() => res(val), delay);                  
  });                                                   
}                                                       

const promises = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].map(it => {
  if (it % 3 === 0) {                                   
    return delayReject(50, it);                         
  } else {                                              
    return delayValue(50, it);                          
  }                                                     
});                                                     

Promise.map(promises, v => {                            
  console.log('mapping', v);                            
  return -v;                                            
}).then(it => {                                         
  console.log('mapped', it);                            
}).catch(err => {                                       
  console.log('error', err);    
});
```

My output, with `node v6.8.1`, is:

```
ssube@localhost ~/questions/40619451 $  > node early-exit.js
waiting to resolve 1                                                      
waiting to resolve 2                                                      
waiting to reject 3                                                       
waiting to resolve 4                                                      
waiting to resolve 5                                                      
waiting to reject 6                                                       
waiting to resolve 7                                                      
waiting to resolve 8                                                      
waiting to reject 9                                                       
mapping 1                                                                 
mapping 2                                                                 
error 3
```

As you may expect, all the promises are scheduled and run, but the `map` does stop running against them after the first failure.

The Bluebird docs mention that:

> The mapper function for a given item is called as soon as possible, that is, when the promise for that item's index in the input array is fulfilled. This doesn't mean that the result array has items in random order, it means that `.map` can be used for concurrency coordination unlike `.all`.

That suggests that the order of mapped items may not be persisted, like it is in the above example. We can test that by adding some noise to the delay:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');                    

function delayNoise(n) {                                
  return n + Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);            
}                                                       

function delayReject(delay, err) {                      
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {                    
    console.log('waiting to reject', err);              
    setTimeout(() => rej(err), delayNoise(delay));      
  });                                                   
}                                                       

function delayValue(delay, val) {                       
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {                    
    console.log('waiting to resolve', val);             
    setTimeout(() => res(val), delayNoise(delay));      
  });                                                   
}                                                       

const promises = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].map(it => {
  if (it % 3 === 0) {                                   
    return delayReject(50, it);                         
  } else {                                              
    return delayValue(50, it);                          
  }                                                     
});                                                     

Promise.map(promises, v => {                            
  console.log('mapping', v);                            
  return -v;                                            
}).then(it => {                                         
  console.log('mapped', it);                            
}).catch(err => {                                       
  console.log('error', err);                            
});
```

Running that yields far more interesting results: if the first promise rejects, then the map ends and does not attempt to map the others. It does short-circuit, as you guessed.

Comment: Why do you use `console.log()` within `resolver` function at `Promise` constructor? `resolver` function will be called in each instance before `resolve` or `reject` are called.

Comment: @guest271314 to verify that the promise body is being executed and show execution order for each body, then the map, then the final resolve/reject. I'm intentionally showing that exact behavior.

Comment: Is OP attempting to determine if `resolver` function will be called? `Array.prototype.map()` will call each function within passed within `callback` before the `Promise` is resolved or rejected.

Comment: @guest271314 there are two questions: "If any of the first 3 promises are rejected, will the other 7 be even started?" and "it's not clear to me what happens if any of them is rejected." The logging from `resolver` answers the first by showing that all promise bodies **are** run, even if some have or will reject, and the logging from `map` answers the second by showing that Bluebird **does** short-circuit.

Comment: _"by showing that Bluebird does short-circuit"_ Note, have  not tried Bluebird `.map()`. What do you mean by "short-circuit"? All of the functions have already been called, then `.map()` awaits the results, yes?

Comment: @guest271314 the `map` function will transform the input promises, much like array's functional `map` method. Most of the OP's question focuses on whether that map callback will be executed on every promise in the input if some fail (as I read it). The answer is no, not in Bluebird.

Comment: @ssube, thank you very much for your answer. I've achieved very similar results. However, my code is a bit different than yours. If you allow me, I could edit your answer with my code and the results. That will probably clarify the questions guest271314 is having. Since the conclusions are the same, I see no point in creating a new answer.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos I would prefer you leave my tests intact, but by all means, feel free to add your own! More evidence is definitely better, since the docs don't seem to explicitly say.

Comment: @ssube Are you referring only to the results of `Promise.map`, not the actual function passed to `Promise.map`? http://plnkr.co/edit/W24kkTxNznJuIs9FTNhn?p=preview

Comment: "You should assume that all promises will execute." Promises cannot be "executed". You can invoke a function which returns a promise, but there is nothing about a promise which could be "executed".